# WCF Service consume with PHP - works with .NET, Error in deserializing request with PHP

Tags: php, vb.net, web-services, wcf, soap-client

I have a WCF service written in VB.net.

When I add a service reference to a project in Visual Studio and communicate with it via VB or C# everything works fine.

But, with PHP I have wasted all afternoon on it and cannot get a response.

My PHP code is:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);  // Enable errors
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
// Declare parameters for soapclient. Need to make sure its set to soap 1.2
$params  = array("soap_version"=> SOAP_1_2,
                "trace"=>1,
                "exceptions"=>1
                );
// Create the soap client
$client = new SoapClient($url,$params);
// add some WSAddressing Headers in. Ensure that you have the Namespace as the address if you are using wsHttpBinding on the endpoint
$actionHeader = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing','Action','http://tempuri.org/ISamProductQ/GetProduct',true);
// "To" header which took ages to figure out and generated errors when missing
$toHeader = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing','To','https://sam.thinkka.com/Api/SamProductQ.svc', true);
$headers = array();
    array_push($headers, $actionHeader)  ;
    array_push($headers, $toHeader)     ;
// Add the headers
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
// Posted variables
    $url = 'https://sam.thinkka.com/api/SamProductQ.svc/Api/SamProductQ.svc/mex?wsdl';
    $sku=  'PRODUCT_SKU';
    $ApiAccess='A VERY LONG ENCODED STRING' ;
    $Site='www.websiteaddress.co.uk';
//Make the call and pass in the variables that we require to go to the server
$retval = $client->__soapCall("GetProduct", array($sku, $ApiAccess, $Site));
```

Equivalent .NET client code (having added the Service Reference in VS):

```
Dim s As New SamProductFeed.SamProductQClient
Dim Result as Sam_Product = s.GetProduct(SKU:="PRODUCT_SKU", ApiAccess:="A long encoded string", QueryingWebsite:="www.websiteaddress.co.uk")
```

The first lines of `GetProduct` function on the service server look like:

```
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)> _
<KnownType(GetType(Sam_Product))> _
Public Class SamProductQ

Implements ISamProductQ
Public Function GetProduct(ByVal SKU As String, ApiAccess As String, QueryingWebsite As String) As Sam_Product Implements ISamProductQ.GetProduct
.....  Do Stuff and return "Sam_Product" complex object
End Function
```

I have the service Web.config set up like this:

```
<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="SamProductQ.Behavior" name="SAM.SamProductQ">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://sam.thinkka.com/Api/SamProductQ.svc"/> 
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SamProductQBinding" contract="SAM.ISamProductQ">
    </endpoint> 
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange">
    </endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

With additional config properties:

```
<behavior name="SamProductQ.Behavior">
    <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetUrl="/Api/SamProductQ.svc/mex"/>
    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
</behavior>

<binding name="SamProductQBinding">
   <security mode="Transport">
       <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
   </security>
</binding>
```

When I run the PHP code above, I get the following error:

> Uncaught SoapFault exception: [s:Sender] The formatter threw an
>   exception while trying to deserialize the message:  Error in
>   deserializing body of request message for operation 'GetProduct'. End
>   element 'Body' from namespace
>   'http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope' expected.  Found element
>   'param1' from namespace ''.

I've seen several comments, questions and articles across the net and in particular on SO. Most are suggesting that I am not passing my three parameters to the service properly, but I am pretty sure I am?

The other thing that occurred to me was whether the string I am passing as "ApiAccess" is too long, but the same post works in .NET.

I would appreciate some assistance with this!

Comment: For a start, you cannot expect to be able to easily consume a WCF service exposed across wsHttpBinding from a non-wcf consumer. The first thing you should try is exposing the service using basicHttpBinding. This will make the service much easy to consume from a non-windows client

Comment: Ok - I have changed to `<endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SamProductQBinding" contract="SAM.ISamProductQ"></endpoint> ` and moved the binding to basicHttpBinding.
Still getting the same error though :(

Comment: Had to change the PHP line to use `SOAP_1_1` too, but still getting the deserialization problem

Answer (score 1):

Well... I never got an answer to this, but by following the tip from @Tom Redfern, I was able to get it working by changing the binding to basicHttpBinding and then changing my PHP code.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="SamProductQBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
      <security mode="Transport" />
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
    </binding>
</basicHttpBinding>

<services>
  <service behaviorConfiguration="SamProductQ.Behavior" name="SAM.SamProductQ">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://sam.thinkka.com/Api/SamProductQ.svc"/> 
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="SamProductQBinding" contract="SAM.ISamProductQ"></endpoint> 
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>        
  </service>
</services>
```

And my PHP code:

```
$url = 'https://sam.thinkka.com/api/SamProductQ.svc/Api/SamProductQ.svc/mex?wsdl';
$params  = array("soap_version"=> SOAP_1_1,
            "trace"=>1,
            "exceptions"=>1
            );
$client = new SoapClient($url, $params);
// Parameters for the API
$ApiAccess='a long encoded string' ;
$Site='www.websiteaddress.co.uk';
$sku=  'RP1-16C';  // for single product
// Make the call and pass in the variables that we require to go to the server
// SINGLE PRODUCT:
$GetProductResult = LowerCaseArray($client->__soapCall("GetProduct", array(array(SKU=>$sku, ApiAccess=>$ApiAccess, QueryingWebsite=>$Site)))->GetProductResult);
```

Now I am getting results